# Android permission error (ls: /storage/emulated/: Permission denied)

Tags: android

I have an issue with working with external storage directory . I read all topics about this problem but still I have this problem 
Some guys said that we should use rooted device but it sounds irrational . All android developers use rooted device for writing their own software ?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o194x.png)

Comment: Do you have given runtime permissions?

Comment: @JawadAhmed If you mean checkSelfPremission yes I did

Comment: And what permissions you are checking?

Comment: @JawadAhmed Write external storage and read external storage

Comment: Can you explain what the issue you are facing?

Comment: You get this "ls: /storage/emulated/: Permission denied" error in Android Studio's Device File Explorer panel, sometimes. Not sure why this suddenly started to happen, even when I create a new emulator it inherits this bug.

Comment: Did you ever figure this our? @JProgrammer